What should the core mass fraction of a habitable planet that orbits very close to a dwarf star be to ensure electromagnetic protection from flares?
After reading this question, I became quite worried about my own habitable world with similar characteristics. Even worse, my star is presumably much younger -- only  8.787 Gyr (out of 50.207 Gyr). Another concerning article is this one, from Wikipedia.
My K6.7V star has a radius of 0.650 R☉, a density of 2.123 D☉, a temperature of 4183K, and a mass of 0.584 M☉. (A similar star is 61 Cygni, shown here.)
 Meanwhile my water-world planet has a radius of 0.924 R⊕, a density of 5.507 g/cm^3, a semi-major axis of 0.34AU and orbital eccentricity of 0.0233 (perihelion is at 0.332 AU, aphelion is at 0.348AU), and a mass of 0.788 M⊕.

Its atmospheric pressure is 1.34 atm and its atmospheric density is 1.636 kg/m^3. The average surface temperature of the planet is 14ºC.

What percentage would my iron core need to be to withstand such frequent and violent flares? Currently, my CMF is at 40.34%. If my atmosphere would help, how thick should it be?

I want to have a red dwarf as a star and keep a habitable water world orbiting it. How should I accomplish this? Should the star change, or something else?

Could you include details in the body of the question about the magnitude of the flares that you're allowing for? You've not told us anything about the orbital distance or eccentricity of the planet or how frequently the flares occur.

@Escapeddentalpatient. I don't know how to calculate the frequency of flares... I added some data for the orbit of the habitable planet, though.

Good start, I've withdrawn the close vote. I'd think that there must be either a way to calculate them (I've no idea) or it's time to create an estimate of what your story needs and go with that.
